# How to create new column in PySpark from existing columns with nullable False

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Is it possible to create a new column in a PySpark dataframe with "nullable: False" using the existing column with no null values but "nullable: True" in schema. I'm struggling to get the answer but there's nothing relevant. Any direction or help would be of great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried that did not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve these by creating a new df from the old one using a schema
e.g

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John Doe", 21), (2, "Simple", 33)], ("id", "name", "age"))

new_schema = df.schema.add("noNulls", StringType(), False) # 3rd parameter states the Nullable property

df = df.withColumn('noNulls', df.id+df.age)

new_df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, new_schema)

new_df.printSchema()
```

This returns the new_df with schema

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- noNulls: string (nullable = false)
```

You can read more about StructType [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html).

**Note**

If you add a column with it's value as literal using `lit` function. It will be created as `nullable=false` by default